# Page cannot be redirected when clicking on advertisment

Tags: support, advertising

I saw an ad with title: [Can I move MSSQL backup files on a running database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266765/can-i-move-mssql-backup-files-on-a-running-database) while viewing question on the main site.

But when I clicked on it, something looked like: Client (me) made a request to somewhere, and the response data contained the Stack Overflow's navigation bar. Then, the data (template) was applied to the ad position. Like this:

> [image: 1]

At the bottom of the ad, after overriding, there was still an option: `Report this ad`

Since it related to Stack Overflow's script(s) rather than the ad content, I think it should be better if I report the problem here.